# Magento 1 api qty_invoiced decimal

Tags: php, soap, magento-1.9, number-formatting

Importing a sale from a 3rd party using SOAP and the quantity parameter always ends up in the Magento completed order rounding up to whole number. Selling in kgs. The following

```
$xmlRequest .=  "<quantity>".number_format($resultSalesOrder[items][$j][qty_invoiced])."</quantity>";
```

Produces

```
<quantity>0.6000</quantity>
```

But in Magento order qty is 1.

Do I need to add a decimal point to the .number_format?

Comment: Which endpoint are you using?

Comment: Updated (thanks for pointing that out!) to include SOAP

Comment: Yes, but which endpoint in the API are you using? Have you checked data type for quantity?